# React Hooks addEventListener undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React hooks, I'm just wondering why the addEventListener is undefined even though I used it inside the `useEffect`.

```
function useHover() {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(true);

    const enter = () => setHovered(true);
    const leave = () => setHovered(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter);
      ref.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave);
      return () => {
        ref.current.removeEventListener('mouseenter', enter);
        ref.current.removeventListener('mouseleave', leave);
      };
    }, [ref]);

    return [ref, hovered];
  }`enter code here`
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting,  Can you share a codesandbox with what your are facing

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty here's the full error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest those commands in the componentDidMount/componentWillMount and that should stage those listeners, but that’s not a best practice.

Here’s the docs I follow when I handle events.

url:  https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Beacause `ref.current` is always undefined. You need to set ref on some html element in order to avoid undefined. Imho, you'll need to have `setRef` function/const in your hook and than return it from the hook like return [ref, setRef, hovered]; Than, in component where you use that hook, when that component mounts set ref to some element.

Update:

Actually, all you need to do is to wrap

```
ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter", enter);
ref.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", leave);
```

with `if (ref.current) { ... }`. Otherwise, you are trying to attach event listeners before html element gets referenced. 
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-villani-6w2dj)

Comment: can you ellaborate your explanations maybe a guide, cause I dont get it actually.

Comment: Can you take a look at this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-bartik-f35jf  which I've created for you? Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, you might not need to return `ref` from hook and than use it in components where your custom hook is used. return just `[setRef, hovered]`. Here is another example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-tu-efzw6